# "Permission denied" error from Adminer with root@localhost

Tags: php, centos, mariadb, selinux, adminer

I'm trying to use [Adminer](https://www.adminer.org) to connect to MariaDB database, but I get "Permission denied" error when I press the Login-button. Note that this is NOT "Access denied" which I'd expect if e.g. password is wrong.

This is my first time using MariaDB, and I'm also quite new to CentOS, do I'm unsure of what is wrong here. Some debugging and settings about my system is listed below.

Connecting to MariaDB from PHP does work, e.g. with this test script:

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root','mypassword')
  or die(mysqli_error());
var_dump($db);
```

Using `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p` from console also works, and also `netstat` confirms that `mysqld` is listening:

```
$ sudo netstat -tlpn | grep mysqld
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      16428/mysqld
```

MariaDB Grants:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show grants;
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@localhost                                                                        |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '...' WITH GRANT OPTION |
| GRANT PROXY ON ''@'%' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION                                    |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Settings in Adminer:

```
System: MySQL
Server: 127.0.0.1
Username: root
Password: mypassword
Database: (none)
```

My system:

```
CentOS 7
Apache 2.4.6
PHP 5.4.16
MariaDB 10.1.16
Adminer 4.2.5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Main reason for this is wrong SELinux setting, but there is also a critical MariaDB bug affecting this.

SELinux has boolean `httpd_can_network_connect_db` which defines whether HTTP server scripts and modules can connect to database server or not. This defaults to `off`:

```
$ getsebool httpd_can_network_connect_db
httpd_can_network_connect_db --> off
```

Turning this `on` and restarting* Apache allows connecting from Adminer using `Server: 127.0.0.1`:

```
sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db on
sudo systemctl restart httpd
```

*) I'm not sure whether restart is really required.

Interestingly trying to connect using `Server: localhost` still doesn't work. This is because of a critical bug in MariaDB 10.1.16 concerning SELinux contexts: [MDEV-10405](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-10405) & [MDEV-10404](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-10404)

Work-around for this bug is to disable `NoNewPrivileges=true` setting.

Create file `/etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d/myfix.conf`:

```
# temporary fix for bug https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-10404
[Service]
NoNewPrivileges=false
```

And then run:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart mariadb
```