# Permission denied when trying to login to adminer in WSL2/Ubuntu

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, adminer

I am trying to setup a local server in Ubuntu om Windows with WSL2. I am not a Linux expert by any measure and don't know exactly what I am doing. Sorry for the long post but I have tried to give as much information as I can.

I have visited a number of sites for instructions (where it all just seems to work) and came up with the following:
Start Ubuntu on Windows 10
Follow the prompts to create the user 'andrew' with password 'andrew' then execute the following commands

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt-get install apache2 php7.4 libapache2-mod-php7.4 mysql-server php7.4-mysql
sudo apt-get install php-curl php-gd php-intl php-json php-mbstring php-xml
sudo service apache2 stop
sudo service mysql stop
sudo systemctl disable apache2
sudo systemctl disable mysql
sudo apt-get install adminer
echo "Alias /adminer.php /usr/share/adminer/adminer.php" | sudo tee /etc/apache2/conf-available/adminer.conf
sudo a2enconf adminer.conf
sudo service apache2 restart
```

ps shows apache is runnung as user www-data

```
sudo usermod -d /var/lib/mysql/ mysql
sudo service mysql start
```

ps shows mysql running as user mysql

```
sudo mysql
    CREATE USER 'andrew'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'andrew';
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'andrew'@'localhost';
    FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
sudo vi /var/www/html/phpinfo.php
    <?php phpinfo();?>
```

Localhost/phpinfo/php displays correctly

```
sudo nano /etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini
    display_errors = On
    display_startup_errors = On
    error_reporting = E_ALL
   22  sudo a2enmod rewrite
   23  sudo service apache2 restart
```

localhost/adminer.php shows the adminer login page but I get "Access denied" when I try to log in as root or as andrew, with or without passwords.

I created a test script (stole it from here ["Permission denied" error from Adminer with root@localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38673409) I did not try the solution as I am not running SELinux)

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','andrew','andrew')
  or die(mysqli_error());
var_dump($db);
```

Which does not throw any errors and displays db info which looks OK.
If I do the same with root and the password andrew (which I use for sudo) then I see two errors (do I need a different password for root?)

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1698): Access denied for user
> 'root'@'localhost' in /var/www/html/sqltest.php on line 2
>
> Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in
> /var/www/html/sqltest.php on line 3

If I

```
sudo mysql
```

and

```
SELECT User,Host FROM mysql.user;
+------------------+-----------+
| User             | Host      |
+------------------+-----------+
| andrew           | localhost |
| debian-sys-maint | localhost |
| mysql.infoschema | localhost |
| mysql.session    | localhost |
| mysql.sys        | localhost |
| root             | localhost |
+------------------+-----------+
```

I can also

```
sudo mysqladmin status -u root -p
sudo mysqladmin status -u andrew -p
sudo mysql -u root -p
sudo mysql -u andrew -p
```

All using password andrew (so my sudo password does seem to work for root), but only as sudo, not as plain andrew

I don't know where to go from here. How do I login to adminer?

Comment: I suppose the mysql root password has not been set, you can try to connect without the ```-p``` option: ```mysql -u root```

Comment: That gets me straight into mysql without prompting for a password. It makes no difference to the Adminer login, which is my real issue.

Comment: Hmm, seems the answer all along was "turn it off and turn it back on again". The macine where I am doing this was shutdown overnight and today I can login to Adminer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not knowing much about PHP and Windows with WSL2 but I think it is the same thing with Django. It seems like while trying to access your resources you get blocked due to the security reasons of ubuntu. so tries to grant access to your resources by the following command.

```
$ chmod 664 ~/to/yourproject/directory/yoursqlname.sql
$ sudo chown :www-data ~/to/yourproject/directory/yoursqlname.sql
$ sudo chown :www-data ~/to/yourproject/directory/
$ sudo chown :www-data ~/to/yourproject/directory/wsgifolder
```

the below command will allow you to access your resource if you are not able to access them after running the above command. In short, the below command will help you access adminer

```
$ sudo find -type d -exec chmod +x {} +
```

then run the following command

```
 $ sudo systemctl restart apache2
 $ sudo systemctl reload apache2
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been through the process again after resetting my Ubuntu instance in WSL2 and the adminer installation definitely works after a complete restart. There is something (I don't know what) that need restarting or reloading, besides the apache2 and mysql services.

Comment: Your answer doesn't seem to offer any solution.

Comment: This is the correct answer! I restarted my windows machine and it worked!